# closestCells() Query Explanation

Tags: mysql

Can someone please explain how this query returns the closest cell near it using the power function? I understand the math and how we return it under id2, but how do we get it to show the id of the closest cell near it with ORDER BY? We order it by the distance, which is by default in ASC order, the smallest distance, and LIMIT it by 1? Does it limit each id2 by 1 so we get the closest one only?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE closestCells()
BEGIN
    select l.id id1,
           (select id 
                from positions r
                where l.id <> r.id
                order by power(l.x - r.x, 2) + power(l.y - r.y, 2) limit 1
           ) id2
        from positions l;
END
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results is always helpful

Comment: That statement won't even compile, you're missing an `AS`, and a procedure's name can only been proceeded by parenthesis (`()`) *if* those parenthesis contain the parameters. The above seems like a mash of an SP and a UDF.

Comment: This looks like MySQL syntax, not SQL Server. Which database are you using?

Comment: <swag> For each row (`l`) in `positions` the subquery finds all of the _other_ (`l.id <> r.id`) rows (`r`) and orders by (the square of) the distance with only the lowest value (`limit 1`) being returned. </swag>

Comment: @Zhorov appears to be right. Apart from the aforementioned syntax errors, `LIMIT` isn't a valid T-SQL operator either (T-SQL uses `TOP`). This makes it even more confusing that the OP only tagged `tsql` to start with. I've removed the RDBMS specific tags and tagged this with SQL. *Hopefully* the OP will return to tag the actual RDBMS they are using.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Sample data would help and I should have provided it. And yes that's right Larnu, LIMIT is not valid in tsql, I edited the tag to mysql.